# Equivalent t-test results in PANDAS?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to learn a bit of PANDAS and so I'm going through some R code and trying to reproduce things in Python.

I have the following simple example

```
tempdat <- data.frame(unit=c('feet','feet','feet','feet','metres','metres','metres','metres'),
                  feet=c(50,45,75,60,26,32,40,45))
t.test(feet~unit, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, var.equal=F, data=tempdat)
```

I want to do the equivalent function in Python, and this is what I have so far, but the results are different.

```
tempdat = pd.DataFrame({'unit':['feet','feet','feet','feet','metres','metres','metres','metres'], 'feet':[50,45,75,60,26,32,40,45]})
feet_group = tempdat[tempdat['unit']=='feet']
metres_group = tempdat[tempdat['unit']=='metres']
stats.ttest_ind(feet_group['feet'], metres_group['feet'], equal_var=False)
```

Comment: Sorry - I rushed this question. I'll have to go back and redo it

Comment: Believe I fixed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face an error in the first line:
tempdat is python built-in dict. So it must have **unique** keys. So after  definition

```
tempdat={'feet':50,'feet':45,'feet':75,'feet':60,'metres':26,'metres':32,'metres':40,'metres':45}
```

you will have only last values:

```
tempdat={'feet': 60, 'metres': 45}
```

Therefore the test results differ